# Python combine integer columns to create multiple columns with suffix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe with a sample of the employee survey results as shown below. The values in the delta columns are just the difference between the FY21 and FY20 columns.

```
Employee           leadership_fy21  leadership_fy20  leadership_delta   comms_fy21 comms_fy20 comms_delta
patrick.t@abc.com  88               50               38                 90         80         10
johnson.g@abc.com  22               82               -60                80         90         -10 
pamela.u@abc.com   41               94               -53                44         60         -16
yasmine.a@abc.com  90               66               24                 30         10         20
```

I'd like to create multiple columns that
i. contain the % in the fy21 values
ii. merge it with the columns with the delta suffix such that the delta values are in a ().

example output would be:

```
Employee           leadership_fy21  leadership_delta  leadership_final comms_fy21 comms_delta comms_final
patrick.t@abc.com  88               38               88% (38)           90         10         90% (10)      
johnson.g@abc.com  22               -60              22% (-60)          80         -10        80% (-10)       
pamela.u@abc.com   41               -53              41% (-53)          44         -16        44% (-16)      
yasmine.a@abc.com  90               24               90% (24)           30         20         30% (20)
```

I have tried the following code but it doesn't seem to work. It might have to do with numpy not being able to combine strings. Appreciate any form of help I can get, thank you.

```
#create a list of all the rating columns
ratingcollist = ['leadership','comms','wellbeing','teamwork']


#create a for loop to get all the columns that match the column list
for rat in ratingcollist:
    cols = df.filter(like=rat).columns
    fy21cols = df[cols].filter(like='_fy21').columns
    deltacols = df[cols].filter(like='_delta').columns

    if len(cols) > 0:
        df[f'{rat.lower()}final'] = (df[fy21cols].values.astype(str) + '%' + '(' + df[deltacols].values.astype(str) + ')')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def yourfunction(ratingcol):
    x=df.filter(regex=f'{ratingcol}(_delta|_fy21)')
    fy=x.filter(regex='21').iloc[:,0].astype(str)
    delta=x.filter(regex='_delta').iloc[:,0].astype(str)

    return(fy+"%("+delta+")")
    
yourfunction('leadership')

0     88%(38)
1    22%(-60)
2    41%(-53)
3     90%(24)
```

Then, using a for loop you can create your columns

```
for i in ratingcollist:
    df[f"{i}_final"]=yourfunction(i)
```

Comment: Hey, it can't seem to work, i'm getting IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Do you have fy21 and delta for every rating column? if not, thats why you are getting this error

Comment: oh yes, you are right, it was the case of naming for the column headers. This works!